# Why my dialogue box login of the Facebook integration isn't supported?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, safari

In my App, I've created Facebook Integration when I click on Facebook login it goes to Safari browser, how can change it to dialogue box login without entering via Safari web browser?

Thanks In Advance.

> [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
>       if (FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.loginType != FBSessionLoginTypeFacebookApplication /*||
>   FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.loginType !=
>   FBSessionLoginTypeSystemAccount*/) {
>           [HUD hide:YES];
>           HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
>           HUD.labelText = @"Signing In";
>
> ```
> [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown,user_friends"]
>                                    allowLoginUI:YES
>                               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
>
>                                   switch (state) {
>                                       case FBSessionStateOpen:{
>
>                                           [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
>                                           [self checkSessionState:state];
>                                           [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection
> ```
>
> *connection, NSDictionary *user, NSError *error) {
>                                                     if (error) {
>                                                         [HUD hide:YES];
>                                                         NSLog(@"error Report :%@",error);
>                                                     }
>                                                     else
>                                                     {
>                                               [HUD hide:YES];
>
> ```
>                                        NSString *userLocation =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n",user.location[@"name"]];
>                                         NSArray* foo = [userLocation componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
>                                         NSString *strCity  = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
>                                         NSString *strState  = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];
>
>
>
>                                                   NSString *linkURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://carzillaapp.com/"];
>                                                   NSString *pictureURL = @"http://www.friendsmash.com/images/logo_large.jpg";
>                                                    //                                                      NSString *pictureURL = @" ";
>
>                                                   // Prepare the native share dialog parameters
>                                                   FBShareDialogParams *shareParams = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
>                                                   shareParams.link = [NSURL URLWithString:linkURL];
>                                                   shareParams.name = @"Download and Checkout CarZilla App!";
>                                                   shareParams.caption= @"An online Car Showroom!";
>                                                   shareParams.picture= [NSURL URLWithString:pictureURL];
>                                                   shareParams.description =
>                                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Both new and old cars available there!"];
>
>                                                   if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:shareParams]){
>
>                                                       [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:shareParams
>                                                                                   clientState:nil
>                                                                                       handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
>                                                                                           if(error) {
>                                                                                               NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
>                                                                                           } else if (results[@"completionGesture"] &&
> ```
>
> [results[@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {
>                                                                                                     NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
>                                                                                                 } else {
>                                                                                                     NSLog(@"Story published.");
>                                                                                                 }
>                                                                                             }];
>
> ```
>                                                   } else {
>
>                                                       // Prepare the web dialog parameters
>                                                       NSDictionary *params = @{
>                                                                                @"name" : shareParams.name,
>                                                                                @"caption" : shareParams.caption,
>                                                                                @"description" : shareParams.description,
>                                                                                @"picture" : pictureURL,
>                                                                                @"link" : linkURL
>                                                                                };
>
>                                                       // Invoke the dialog
>                                                       [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
>                                                                                              parameters:params
>                                                                                                 handler:
>                                                        ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
>                                                            if (error) {
>                                                                NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
>                                                            } else {
>                                                                if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
>                                                                    NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
>                                                                } else {
>                                                                    NSLog(@"Story published.");
>                                                                }
>                                                            }}];
>                                                   }
>
>
>
>
>
>                                                   NSDictionary *params = @{
>                                                                            @"name" : shareParams.name,
>                                                                            @"caption" : shareParams.caption,
>                                                                            @"description" : shareParams.description,
>                                                                            @"picture" : pictureURL,
>                                                                            @"link" : linkURL
>                                                                            };
>
>                                                   [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
>                                                                                                 message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Checkout the CarZilla App!"]
>                                                                                                   title:@"Invite"
>                                                                                              parameters:params
>                                                                                                 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
> ```
>
> {
>                                                                                                           if (error) {
>                                                                                                               // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
>                                                                                                               NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
>                                                                                                           } else {
>                                                                                                               if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
>                                                                                                                   // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
>                                                                                                                   NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
>                                                                                                               } else {
>                                                                                                                   NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
>                                                                                                               }
>                                                                                                           }}
>                                                          ];
>
> ```
>                                         SignUpViewController *faceblogin = [[SignUpViewController alloc]init];
>                                         faceblogin.firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",user.first_name];
>                                         faceblogin.lastName = user.last_name;
>                                         faceblogin.email =[user objectForKey:@"email"];
>                                         faceblogin.city = strCity;
>                                         faceblogin.state = strState;
>                                         faceblogin.fblogin = YES;
>                                         fbFailure = YES;
>                                         fbMsg = YES;
>                                         faceblogin.accountType = @"Individual Buyer/Seller";
>                                         //faceblogin.isPhoneno = YES;
>                                         [self presentViewController:faceblogin animated:YES completion:nil];
>                                               }
>                                           }];
>                                           break;
>                                       }
>                                       case FBSessionStateClosed:{
>                                           [HUD hide:YES];
>                                           NSLog(@"facebook values");
>
>                                       }
>                                       case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:{
>                                           [HUD hide:YES];
>                                           if ((!fbFailure && fbMsg) || error.code == 2) {
>                                               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unfortunately, we
> ```
>
> were not able to log you in using your Facebook credentials."
>   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
>                                                     fbMsg = NO;
>                                                     [alert show];
>                                                 }
>                                                 [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
>                                                 break;
>                                             }
>                                             default:
>                                                 break;
>                                         }
>                                     } ];
>       }
>
> ```
> else{
>
>     NSLog(@"accounts");    }
> ```

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Facebook has changed some of its API, after login to facebook ,it will open your app again.

Comment: Are you using FBLoginView class to maintain the FB sessions ?

Comment: I have posted my code. I am using this code to login and after login the user will be asked to share on wall and invite their friends.

Comment: @user3655029 check this link- http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-manual/ it might help u.. But as far as I know for providing the necessary permissions to your app it will go to safari browser. But in real device this doesn't happen if the FB app is installed. HTH :)

Comment: yes when FB app is intalled, it wont ask for login. but when FB app is un installed, it takes to safari browser for login.